# Can an employer require employees to be COVID-19 tested at their own expense?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, employment

In this case, the employer is a medium-sized ENT office. Some employees are young single mothers who don't have the resources to comply with this. The question also applies to non-medical employers, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "require".

In case of at-will employment — where the employer can fire an employee for any or no reason (other than that being discrimination of a member of the [protected groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_group)) — it would be perfectly legal for the employer to fire an employee who does not comply with that request.

But that aside, no (unless such testing was a term of the employment agreement, be it written or verbal). No party to a contract can require the other party to perform what the contract terms did not include.

Comment: Thanks for this response.  In a right-to-work state I would guess that at-will employment is not assumed but would be stated specifically in sign-on documents, but I'm not sure. This question may have been better phrased as 'if an employer has received a covid-19 SBA loan,  can they require covid-19 employee testing to be done at employee's expense'.  I have a feeling that 'rules' concerning covid-19 responses are changing daily.